# nodejs promise just not waiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, requestify

I'm completely rewriting my question do boil it down even further.

Why, in the following code, does `x()` equate to `undefined` instead of `success` which is logged to the console by `console.log('success');`

The last line finishes executing in the console; then the `.then()` call back is triggered.

How can I make it so `x()` returns the 'success' value before the last line begins to execute.

Even yF() evaluates to `undefined`.  However, .then() is echoing `th y: success`.

```
const promise = require('promise');
const requestify = require('requestify');


function x() {
    requestify.get('https://<redacted>/')
        .then(function (d) {
            console.log('success', d.code);
            return 'success';
        })
        .fail(function (f) {
            console.log('fail', f.code);
            return 'fail';
        });
    ;
}


var yF = function () {
    yP   .then(function (th) { console.log("th", th); return th; })
        .catch(function (fl) { console.log("fl", fl); return fl; });
}


var yP = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        if (1 == 1) {
            resolve("y: success");
        } else {
            reject(new Error("y: fail"));
        }
    }
);




console.log("hello", x());
console.log("world", yF());
```

Comment: please explain further. Are you saying that the code in the then clause of requestify.get gets fired before the request is completed?

Comment: Are you completing the request in the backed inside then after doing all operation

Answer (score 0):

The function `x` does not return a value. This example may help:

```
> function foo() { console.log('hi from foo'); }
undefined
> console.log('calling foo', foo());
hi from foo
calling foo undefined
```

You need to return the promise in your function. Function `x` could change like this:

```
function x() {
    return requestify.get('https://<redacted>/')
        .then(function (d) {
            console.log('success', d.code);
            return 'success';
        })
        .fail(function (f) {
            console.log('fail', f.code);
            return 'fail';
        });
}
```

Now you can call `x` with `then`:

```
x().then(result => assert(result === 'success'));
```

Comment: Maybe not for you, but for me the console.log("hello,,, x().then() resolves to `hello { state: 'pending' }`.  thanks for the reminder that I can return the `requestify()`  that alone turned on a lightbuld

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1) `x()` ~ I'll call, pass a variable forward

2) `yP()`~ consuming a promise

```
const promise = require('promise');
const requestify = require('requestify');

var f = "";


function yP() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        requestify.get('https://<redacted>')
            .then(function (da) {
                var fpt = "success(yP):" + da.code.toString();
                console.log('success-yP', fpt);
                resolve(fpt);
            })
            .catch(function (ca) {
                var fpc = "fail(yP):" + ca.code.toString();
                console.log('fail-yP', fpc);
                reject(fpc);
            });
    });
}


function x() {
    requestify.get('https://<redacted>/')
        .then(function (da) {
            f = "success(x):" + da.code.toString();
            console.log('success-x', f);
            consumef();
        })
        .catch(function (ca) {
            f = "fail(x):" + ca.code.toString();
            console.log('fail-x', ca);
            consumef();
        });
    ;
}


function consumef() {
    console.log("hello", f);

}



x();
yP()
    .then(function (fyPt) { console.log('yP().then', fyPt); })
    .catch(function (fyPc) { console.log('yP().catch', fyPc); });
```

> Debugger listening on [::]:5858
>
> success-yP success(yP):200
>
> yP().then success(yP):200
>
> success-x success(x):200
>
> hello success(x):200

Comment: Read my answer again. You do not need to create the extra promise in your `yP` function, just return the value.